# Webpack with Tailwind CSS JIT integration

Tags: wordpress, webpack, wordpress-theming, tailwind-css

I'm currently having a hard time integrating the Tailwind JIT compiler with Webpack.js.
At the moment almost everything is working (custom colors, custom fonts, custom media queries etc...) except for the JIT compiler. Anyone has a clue what I'm doing wrong? (running on a Wordpress environment)

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Based on the answer of Karl Hill I updated my dependencies, debugged most of it but JIT Compiler is still nog active (should be activated by default in tailwindcss 3.0 ?) Anyone has an idea?

**functions.php**

```
<?php

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', function () {
    wp_enqueue_script('main', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/dist/main.bundle.js', [], '1.0.0', true);
    wp_enqueue_style('main', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/dist/main.css', [], '1.0.0', 'all');
});
```

**Package.json**

```
  "name": "webpack",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "TAILWIND_MODE=watch webpack --config webpack.config.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.13",
    "css-loader": "^6.7.3",
    "postcss": "^8.4.21",
    "postcss-loader": "^7.0.2",
    "style-loader": "^3.3.1",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.2.4",
    "webpack": "^5.75.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^5.0.1"
  }
}
```

**postcss.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
    plugins: [
        require('tailwindcss')("./tailwind.config.js"),
        require('autoprefixer'),
    ]
};
```

**tailwind.config.js**

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: [
    "**/*.php",
    "*.php",
  ],
  theme: {
    screens: {
      sm: '320px',
      md: '768px',
      lg: '1024px',
      xl: '1920px',
    },
    extend: {
      colors: {
        customBlue: '#0F1D51',
        customBeige: '#CBAD7E',
        customEgg: '#FFF9EF',
      },
      borderWidth: {
        '3': '3px',
      },
      fontSize: {
        'base': ['1rem', {
          lineHeight: '2rem',
          letterSpacing: '-0.01em',
        }],
        'xl': ['1.25rem', {
          lineHeight: '2rem',
          letterSpacing: '-0.01em',
        }],
        '4xl': ['2.5rem', {
          lineHeight: '1',
          letterSpacing: '-0.01em',
        }],
        '7xl': ['4.875rem', {
          lineHeight: '1',
          letterSpacing: '-0.01em',
        }]
      },
      fontFamily: {
        sans: [
          '"Roboto"',
          'system-ui',
          '-apple-system',
          'BlinkMacSystemFont',
          '"Segoe UI"',
          '"Helvetica Neue"',
          'Arial',
          '"Noto Sans"',
          'sans-serif',
          '"Apple Color Emoji"',
          '"Segoe UI Emoji"',
          '"Segoe UI Symbol"',
          '"Noto Color Emoji"',
        ],
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  mode: "development",
  context: path.resolve(__dirname, "assets"),
  output: {
    filename: "main.bundle.js",
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "assets/dist")
  },
  watch: true,
  module: {
    rules: [{
      test: /\.css$/,
      use: [{
          loader: 'css-loader',
          options: {
            importLoaders: 1
          }
        },
        {
          loader: 'postcss-loader',
          options: {
            postcssOptions: {
              plugins: [
                require('tailwindcss'),
                require('autoprefixer')
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }]
  }
}
```

Comment: If you upgrade to Tailwind 3.x you don't need to worry about including JIT. Version 1.x has no JIT option, you'd have to upgrade to version 2.x.

Comment: I upgraded my depencies but JIT Compiler is still not functioning, i updated the code in my original question. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Nevermind, i forgot including a dependency, works like a charm now! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Upgraded tailwind css to version ^3.2.4.

Works like a charm now.